# Generate html code which depends on a parameter from java

Tags: java, html, xml

I want to be able to generate html pages where some parts of the html should depend on some parameters. 
My idea is that I could have a template like OneMailTemplate.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MailTemplate</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Bla bla bla</p>
    <someComponent>
    <p>Bla bla</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and then get some method to replace the tag

```
<someComponent>
```

with some generated html code.
Is there a way to do this in java without the use of StringTokenizer? 
I am also open to suggestions about how I can do this in another way.

Comment: Are you using servlets or JSP pages, or, how do you generate this in Java and get it to the browser?

Comment: It is not going to the browser right away. It should be a html file which depends on which user is logged in in my webapp. This html file is then going to be send via javaMail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I like XSLT, I think it may be a bit heavy for this purpose. [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) is made for this kind of thing. It can take an HTML template with parameters like ${name} in the html and create your output without being dependent upon a jsp.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of overkill to use a Java program to do this...

But the proper way in Java would be to use DOM functions to find the tag, create your replacement subtree, and output the result.

If your replacement is static, you should use XSLT instead.  If the replacement is dynamic, consider using JSP instead of a custom preprocessor - JSP is designed for this case.

Comment: Can I use JSP if I as I mentioned above want to get a html file which I can send via javaMail. I need to get the source from the generated html page and send it via mail without the user seeing this page.

Comment: You can save the generated HTML page, or even send it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org) for my mail templates.